# Excel custom number format for log data

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a custom format for Excel axis number formatting that suits log axes, removing unnecessary zeros?

[image]

Comment: Did U try the General Format,,, has worked for me !

Comment: Thanks @RajeshS - All this time I'd been assuming it needed to be a number but that works straight away

Comment: Glad to help U,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, this can be achieved using the General format rather than using a number format.